# MASL: msal-node does not work behind proxy

Tags: azure-ad-msal

msal-node keeps complaining network error if using proxy

**Error:**

ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints

**Config:**

```
 system: {
      loggerOptions: {
          loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
              console.log(message);
          },
          piiLoggingEnabled: false,
          logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Info,
      },
      proxyUrl: "http://my.proxy.com:81"
  },
```

According to the [document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/configuration.md) the configuration seems correct. Have no idea why it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out I have to implement the networkClient meanwhile:

```
networkClient: proxyClient, // your custom proxy client that implements sendGetRequestAsync and sendPostRequestAsync
proxyUrl: proxyUrl
```